# How can I use apache's rewrite URI to serve 404.php at /404/?

Tags: .htaccess

How can I serve this file:

`http://www.domain.com/404.php`

Whenever my users go to:

`http://www.domain.com/404` or `http://www.domain.com/404/`

Using .htaccess?

I tried this:

> RewriteRule 404 /404.php [L]

With the following error:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding with a 404 will cause HTTPd to do the right thing.

```
RewriteRule 404 - [R=404]
```